# npx amplify-app@latest failed to create a Base Amplify Project

Tags: reactjs, npm, aws-amplify, npm-scripts

I am creating a react-app using this steps:

1. `npx create-react-app amplify-datastore --use-npm`
2. `cd amplify-datastore`
3. `npx amplify-app@latest` #in this last step i will show you the output i get in powershell:

`npx: installed 117 in 15.511s ✅ Found Amplify CLI version 4.29.4 � Creating base Amplify project Note: It is recommended to run this command from the root of your app directory ? Enter a name for the environment (dev) ❌ Failed to create base Amplify Project`

I have tried several times and I still get the same issue. Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as you but found success by running

```
amplify init
```

within the app directory. In your case after "cd amplify-datastore".

"amplify init" will initialize a new Amplify project.

Then I ran

```
npx amplify-app@latest
```

and

```
npm install aws-amplify aws-amplify-react-native @react-native-community/netinfo
```

Then in the CLI, I added a new API by

```
amplify add api
```

A tutorial I was following used the exact same steps as you but it didn't work out so resorted to reading up the Amplify DataStore manual and I came up with those steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, please check if your username has a space e.g. instead of

> c:\Users\UserName

, it could be

> C:\Users\Username Name